# Flink to NiFi connector

Tags: scala, apache-flink, apache-nifi

I need some help with transferring data from the output NiFi port to Flink using Scala code.

I'm stuck at `.addSource()` function. It asks for additional parameters ([OUT]) but when I provide them I keep getting an error. Scala code and the error message are below.

```
package flinkTest

import java.nio.charset.{Charset, StandardCharsets}

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.nifi.NiFiSource
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.nifi.NiFiDataPacket

import org.apache.nifi.remote.client.{SiteToSiteClient, SiteToSiteClientConfig}

object NifiFlow {
  def main(): Unit = {

    // get the execution environment
    val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = 
    StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    // get input data by connecting to NiFi
    val clientConfig: SiteToSiteClientConfig = new SiteToSiteClient.Builder()
      .url("http://localhost:8080/nifi")
      .portName("Data to flink")
      .requestBatchCount(2)
      .buildConfig()

    val nifiSource: SourceFunction[NiFiDataPacket] = new NiFiSource(clientConfig)
```

Here's the piece

```
    val streamSource: DataStream[NiFiDataPacket] = 
    env.addSource(nifiSource).setParallelism(2)
```

and some more code

```
    val dataStream = streamSource.map(dataPacket => new String(dataPacket.getContent, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))

    dataStream.print()

    env.execute()
  }
}
```

1) With [OUT]

```
Error:(28, 76) value nifiSource of type org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction[org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.nifi.NiFiDataPacket] does not take type parameters.
    val streamSource: DataStream[NiFiDataPacket] = env.addSource(nifiSource[NiFiDataPacket]).setParallelism(2)
```

2) Without [OUT]

```
Error:(28, 66) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction[org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.nifi.NiFiDataPacket]
 required: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.function.source.SourceFunction[?]
    val streamSource: DataStream[NiFiDataPacket] = env.addSource(nifiSource).setParallelism(2)
```

Example was taken [here](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-connectors/flink-connector-nifi/src/test/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/nifi/examples/NiFiSourceTopologyExample.java) and rewritten to Scala.

I will appreciate any advice.

UPD2

```
package flinkTest

import org.apache.nifi.remote.client.{SiteToSiteClient, SiteToSiteClientConfig}
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.nifi._

object NifiFlow {
  def main(): Unit = {

    // get the execution environment
    val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    // get input data by connecting to NiFi
    val clientConfig: SiteToSiteClientConfig = new SiteToSiteClient.Builder()
      .url("http://localhost:8080/nifi")
      .portName("Data to flink")
      .requestBatchCount(2)
      .buildConfig()

    val nifiSource = new NiFiSource(clientConfig)

    val streamSource: DataStream[String] = env
      .addSource(nifiSource)
      .map(x => x.getAttributes().toString)

    env.execute()
  }
}
```

ERROR

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:41218', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException: Interfaces and abstract classes are not valid types: interface org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.nifi.NiFiDataPacket
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateGetForClass(TypeExtractor.java:871)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateGetForClass(TypeExtractor.java:863)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.createTypeInfoWithTypeHierarchy(TypeExtractor.java:406)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.privateCreateTypeInfo(TypeExtractor.java:197)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TypeExtractor.createTypeInfo(TypeExtractor.java:184)
    at flinkTest.NifiFlow$.main(NiFiFlow.scala:23)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a special implementation of execution environment for scala

[org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/scala/StreamExecutionEnvironment.html)

just use it instead of `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment`

Comment: Does not help. It somehow can't transform type class.                           
 Error:(37, 38) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction[**org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.nifi.NiFiDataPacket**]
 required: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.function.source.SourceFunction[**?**]
    val streamSource = env.addSource(nifiSource)

Comment: can you attach a full file with your modified code and full error ?

Comment: updated the initial post. Code too long to be pasted into comments.

Comment: what is your flink version?

Comment: I see there is a problem in package name of SourceFunction class. StreamExecutionEnvironment requires `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.function.source.SourceFunction` that i can find only in `flink v0.8.1`  and you passing `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction` that appeared since `flink v0.9`. note that there is `.function.` vs `.functions.` I guess you have different libraries in your classpath.

Comment: <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
<artifactId>flink-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.4-SNAPSHOT</version>

Comment: I've noticed the difference in one letter "s". Never thought it may be an issue. It's really confusing :-)

Comment: Now there are two errors: `Error:(23, 54) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.nifi.NiFiSource
 required: org.apache.flink.streaming.api.function.source.SourceFunction[org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.nifi.NiFiDataPacket]
    val nifiSource: SourceFunction[NiFiDataPacket] = new NiFiSource(clientConfig)
Error:(25, 37) can't expand macros compiled by previous versions of Scala
    val streamSource = env.addSource(nifiSource)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149499/discussion-between-anna-vergeles-and-daggett).

Comment: I've completely renewed libraries and dependencies. I have no error at compile time, but I still have error at the `.addSource` line. Now `env.addSource(nifiSource)` gives the result `Error evaluating method: 'createTypeInformation'.`

Answer (score 1):

`env.addSource(nifiSource)` works only with prior setting `env.getJavaEnv.getConfig.disableClosureCleaner()`

Probably, scala sources in this open-source project should be updated a bit (located in flink-scala_2.11...jar).